# MQL4. Help Making One Pending Order Cancel When The Other Is Triggered

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, forex, mt4

I have tried to make 2 orders that vary in direction. When one triggers make the other cancel but I am having trouble making the other cancel. I have been searching the web for hours and have no idea how to do it. I will link the Close order multifunction I have tried to use before as it seems promsing but dont no  how to implement it. If you guys could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks

[My EA](https://pastebin.com/HmhTfCNn)

```
  //Close pending orders
  case OP_BUYLIMIT  : result = OrderDelete( OrderTicket() );
  case OP_BUYSTOP   : result = OrderDelete( OrderTicket() );
  case OP_SELLLIMIT : result = OrderDelete( OrderTicket() );
  case OP_SELLSTOP  : result = OrderDelete( OrderTicket() );
```

[The EA that I need to implement](https://pastebin.com/9ryk9XTx)

Comment: do you need to cancel pending sell if pending buy is activated (became market)? like OCO orders ? or what ?

Comment: Sorry it's like a hedging thing. If the buy is triggered cancel the pending sell and vice versa. I hope that helps

Comment: google OCO orders, there's an article in MQL5.com for that, available via MT editor

Comment: Thanks man I'll give it a sus